# Incremental duplicates

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, duplicates

I've list of integers, which the list is *circular*. I want to find consecutive duplicates, instead of them place duplicate number + 1 to the start position. Also need to do this until there are no consecutive duplicates in the list or list is empty. I tried while loops with different forms but couldn't reach my goal. Tried cycling with `itertools.cycle`, cause -1 and 0 are also consecutive, but couldn't remove or insert. Also finding out when to stop is problem, tried `int_list == list(set(int_list))` but there might some non-consecutive duplicates, so that create a infinite loop. Here is an example:

```
int_list = [1,1,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,7,8,8,9,10,8,11,4,12,15,13,14,14,15,16,1]
processed_list = [11,8,11,4,12,15,13,17]
```

Edit:

The original problems is in [this](https://www.codewars.com/kata/616ee43a919fae003291d18f/) Codewars kata.

Comment: Write a function that determines if there are any consecutive duplicates. Then you can do `while there_are_duplicates(int_list):`

Comment: Or you can use a variable that records whether you made any modifications to the list. If you get through the list without doing any replacements, you break out of the main loop.

Comment: i tried to create a bool function for detect duplicates but the list is circular so i couldn't find a way to detect it.

Comment: Python doesn't have circular lists. You just need an additional check on whether `int_list[0] == int_list[-1]`

Comment: i know, but minus indexing is create a circular list illusion. there are edge cases like all items could be same. i tried to create a function with loops but as i mention i couldn't find a way.

Comment: If the list is circular, how do you know where to start? This could affect the output if you started at lets say the two `7`s, then the output would be `[7, 11, 8, 11, 4, 12, 15, 13, 17]`

Comment: I suggest you try doing this by hand on paper, then from that process you may be able to figure out the python algorithm.

Comment: What exactly are you asking? The question just seems to list several tasks you are struggling with – what *specific* problem do you want an answer to?

Comment: I want to find consecutive duplicates, instead of them place duplicate number + 1 to the start position until there are none.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `deque` is close to a circular list, because it allows to rotate the list. I took advantage of that in the code below.

The algorithm compares the `item[0]` with the next item `item[1]` and also the previous item (in circular sense) `item[-1]` discarding all dups and incrementing the original `item[0]` if any dups were found.

If there was no duplicate found, the list is rotated and the process is repeated with the new `item[0]`.

The process stops if there was a full length list rotation without finding a dup.

```
# Version 3

from collections import deque

def process(inp):
    circ = deque(inp)
    rcnt = 0    # rotations without finding a dup
    while rcnt < len(circ):
        n = circ[0]
        isdup = False
        while len(circ) >= 1 and circ[1] == n:
            isdup = True
            circ.popleft()
        while len(circ) >= 1 and circ[-1] == n:
            isdup = True
            circ.pop()
        if isdup:
            circ[0] = n+1
            rcnt = 0
        else:
            circ.rotate(1)
            rcnt += 1
        # print(list(circ)) # uncomment to watch the progress
    return list(circ)

test = [1,1,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,7,8,8,9,10,8,11,4,12,15,13,14,14,15,16,1]
print(process(test))
```

With uncommented debug `print`:

```
[2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 7, 8, 8, 9, 10, 8, 11, 4, 12, 15, 13, 14, 14, 15, 16]
[3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 7, 8, 8, 9, 10, 8, 11, 4, 12, 15, 13, 14, 14, 15, 16]
[4, 4, 5, 6, 7, 7, 8, 8, 9, 10, 8, 11, 4, 12, 15, 13, 14, 14, 15, 16]
[5, 5, 6, 7, 7, 8, 8, 9, 10, 8, 11, 4, 12, 15, 13, 14, 14, 15, 16]
[6, 6, 7, 7, 8, 8, 9, 10, 8, 11, 4, 12, 15, 13, 14, 14, 15, 16]
[7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 9, 10, 8, 11, 4, 12, 15, 13, 14, 14, 15, 16]
[8, 8, 8, 9, 10, 8, 11, 4, 12, 15, 13, 14, 14, 15, 16]
[9, 9, 10, 8, 11, 4, 12, 15, 13, 14, 14, 15, 16]
[10, 10, 8, 11, 4, 12, 15, 13, 14, 14, 15, 16]
[11, 8, 11, 4, 12, 15, 13, 14, 14, 15, 16]
[16, 11, 8, 11, 4, 12, 15, 13, 14, 14, 15]
[15, 16, 11, 8, 11, 4, 12, 15, 13, 14, 14]
[14, 15, 16, 11, 8, 11, 4, 12, 15, 13, 14]
[15, 15, 16, 11, 8, 11, 4, 12, 15, 13]
[16, 16, 11, 8, 11, 4, 12, 15, 13]
[17, 11, 8, 11, 4, 12, 15, 13]
[13, 17, 11, 8, 11, 4, 12, 15]
[15, 13, 17, 11, 8, 11, 4, 12]
[12, 15, 13, 17, 11, 8, 11, 4]
[4, 12, 15, 13, 17, 11, 8, 11]
[11, 4, 12, 15, 13, 17, 11, 8]
[8, 11, 4, 12, 15, 13, 17, 11]
[11, 8, 11, 4, 12, 15, 13, 17]
[17, 11, 8, 11, 4, 12, 15, 13]
[13, 17, 11, 8, 11, 4, 12, 15]

the last line is the result:
[13, 17, 11, 8, 11, 4, 12, 15]
```

Comment: thanks for response. but still there is index problem. when input is [7,5,5,6,8,9,10,12,10,8] returns [7, 8, 9, 10, 12, 10, 8, 7].

Comment: @ÜmitKara Thank you for the feedback. The number of loop iterations is too small. Give me some time to analyze, I will correct it.

Comment: @ÜmitKara I have updated the loop condition, I hope the problem is fixed.

Comment: Thanks, great work. i wasn't aware of 'finally' keyword, that cause a lot of wasted time.

Comment: I'm glad I could help, here the `finally` could be replaced by proper length checks to avoid the `IndexError` and as I'm looking at it would be also better IMHO. I will update it last time.